# Laravel 5 Authentification issue with "remember"

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have a phenomen that I do not understand about saving a session in Laravel 5.1

When my user connects by checking the "remember" box, I see the cookie "remember ..." which arrives on his computer. And when he does not check this box the cookie does not happen. See image below.

[image]

On the database side, the column "remember_token" is well fed.

When the same user closes his browser and relaunch the application : it works, he is well recognized.

The mechanical is working.

The problem is when he tries again later in a few hours, at the time the app recognizes no more.

My code is very classic, I do not think it's the origin of the issue.

Probably a config problem somewhere, but what?

Thanks in advance for your help.

dominique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/session.php find "lifetime", this is where define session lifetime, change it to what you want.

Comment: thanks. And if I want a long long time (for exemple 1 week), does it mean that I must change this line to : 'lifetime' => 10080 ? or does this parameter just for very short sessions ?

Comment: it doesn't matter how long you set to it, i set it one month.

Comment: Ok perfect. I will set up this parameter to 1 month too. Is there any impacts on the server (about the ram or else) ?

Comment: if your session driver is file ,only will take the volume of your harddisk,basiclly won't affect much